# Changing Facebook Metatags in SPA, but OG meta tag changes not recognized when shared

Tags: jquery, html, facebook, meta-tags, facebook-opengraph

I have the following code to set for default Facebook meta info.

```
<meta property="og:type" content="music.song">
<meta property="og:title" content="cXc Music (Alpha)">
<meta property="og:description" content="Find underground music from around the world on cXc Music, an app by @currentxchange">
<meta property="og:image" content="images/cXc-Alpha-App-2.1[600].png">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="THISHASLEGITID">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="cXc Music">
```

My goal is to change this info whenever a post loads. This is a SPA, so the info loads and then changes the meta data and the URL in the browser.

I have this jQuery code that sets the meta tags as follow each time a new song displays is loaded.

```
$("meta[property='og:image']").attr('content', song.thumbnail_url);
$("meta[property='og:description']").attr('content', ('Listen to '+ song.title +' and find music from around the globe with cXc Music, an app by @currentxchange'));
$("meta[property='og:title']").attr('content', (song.title + ' on cXc Music'));
```

Currently, just the first tags I set show up for FB no matter what, but twitter changes the title for each song loaded, as desired.

I am using JSsocials.

The similar Twitter title seems to work, but nothing is working on Facebook. You can see the [alpha of the app here](https://music.cxc.world) and see what I mean.

Comment: Changing them with Javascript doesn't matter. Facebook will go to the URL and scrape it. When it does it will not execute Javascript. So what ever you return in the tags are what Facebook will use

Comment: I understand, but why does this work with Twitter? When the share button is clicked, the code is executed. So is Twitter reading the page then and Facebook is making a separate call to the URL?

Comment: Could be it. I don't know how Twitter works.

Comment: Used this: http://drib.tech/programming/dynamically-change-facebook-open-graph-meta-data-javascript